# How to verify all method calls in Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I've got a JUnit test with a few methods using Mockito testing. I have quite a plenty experience with EasyMock (although not recent) so I've organized it like that:

```
@Before
public void before() {
    myAPI = mock(MyAPI.class);
}

@After
public void after() {
    verify(myAPI);
    reset(myAPI);
}
```

The methods register some calls on mock, if they need them.

But I've got an exception:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
>   Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
>   -> at de.datev.shared.spdvz.util.UserInfoUtilTest.after(UserInfoUtilTest.java:45)
>
> Example of correct verification:
>       verify(mock).doSomething()

I know I could do `verify(myAPI).doSomething(someArgs)` but:

1. I'd have to do it in each method
2. I'd have to repeat the same arguments, as those used in `when`

Is there any method to simply verify, if all the methods that were registered on `when` were actually called? EasyMock works that way, and it was very convinient...

Comment: To me, it seems wrong to both stub and verify the same interaction, in most cases.  If the return value of a method is important, then the test should fail if the method is not called, because the return value that you stub won't be used in the subsequent test execution.  However, if the return value of a method is unimportant, then there's no point in stubbing it.

Comment: I didn't find this in time to edit it into my last comment, but Szczepan Faber made the point about stubbing or verifying but not both, in [a blog post](http://monkeyisland.pl/2008/04/26/asking-and-telling/)

Comment: @DavidWallace This argument about not verifying stubbed calls never made much sense to me. If you stub a call in a test, it's only because you do expect the CUT to make it. If it does not, I think everyone would agree that the test *should* fail, regardless of how the return value was supposed to be used. The mocking tool, ideally, should ensure that such a test does not pass. For a practical example, say a developer temporarily comments out a line calling the stubbed method, then forgets to uncomment it later; the test that was supposed to catch such an error may happily continue to pass...

Comment: @Rogério If you have stubbed that method X returns value Y, then it must be the case that value Y is going to be used somehow, otherwise the stubbing would be pointless.  So your test must contain EITHER a verification of some subsequent method call to which Y (or some derivative) is passed, OR an assertion that some particular value is Y (or some derivative).  Now, if it happens that X is not called, then that verification or assertion involving Y must fail, because you won't have introduced Y into the SUT at all.  Therefore, verifying the call to X is redundant.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes, what you say is fine, but it's not the whole story.  The fact is, there is no guarantee the test will satisfy one of the two conditions you described, and that doesn't necessarily make it a poor test. For example, and this is very common, a test may stub X to return Y simply because a method executed during the test needs it, but this is something not meant to be verified in this particular test. Maybe some other test does verify it and will fail, but you still can end up with a test passing when it should fail.

Comment: @Rogério I agree with you completely.  It is very common that a test will stub X to return Y, but not need to verify this.  So this is the case where you will stub but not verify.  My point, and Szczepan's point in the blog post, is that a particular test will EITHER need to stub a method, OR need to verify that the method is called.  But almost never both.  There ARE a very small number of cases where you WILL want to both stub and verify the same method; but if you're doing it as a matter of course, you're doing something wrong.  And I believe THAT is why Mockito keeps stubbing and ...

Comment: ... verification as two entirely separate functions.

Comment: @DavidWallace I just found a good example that shows the importance of the mocking library failing the test when a stubbed call is not fulfilled: chapter 10 of the [Mockito Cookbook](http://www.amazon.com/Mockito-Cookbook-Marcin-Grzejszczak/dp/1783982748/ref=pd_sim_sbs_b_3?ie=UTF8&refRID=0VR0MNRQDNWD51R1JZFB), whose pages are currently available for free viewing at Amazon. In it, the example Mockito test explicitly verifies two stubbings. But without these verifications, the test *cannot* be written TDD-style, because any version of the CUT which happened to return `false` would pass it!

Comment: @Rogério I'm afraid I can't see that - Amazon must have made it available in your area but not mine.  However, I did mention in my last comment that there are a small number of cases where it's necessary to stub and verify.  The thing is that this is very rare - a kind of last resort, and certainly well worth having to code explicitly.  So I really wouldn't expect the Mockito team ever to provide a feature that will "stub and verify" in a single method call; which is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @DavidWallace Ah, ok; you can also see the full example test at the  [github repository](https://github.com/marcingrzejszczak/mockito-cookbook). I must say this wasn't the first time I saw Mockito users writing tests that both stub and verify the same calls; it's apparently not so rare. And Mockito already [*almost* has](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#18) this feature; I imagine they could easily add a validation to the `validateMockitoUsage()` implementation that checks for any unused stubbings.

Comment: @DavidWallace I find I *often* want to stub and verify: When I have a method with a side effect, which returns a status code, I must stub it to return the code, and then verify that it was in fact called.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is not possible.
[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mockito/sBJuhslFQMY) is an old discussion where two of the maintainers are stating their opinion on such a feature.
The discussion is pretty old but as far as i can tell there still isn't support for that in the current Mockito version.

> In Mockito verification is explicit. So you basically verify(assert)
>   if a particular invocations has already taken place or not and it's up
>   to you to choose what's important to be examined.
>   Mockito has also much stronger separation between stubbing and mocking
>   functionality. Thus, it let you stub some calls to make the code pass
>   the path you intended without verifying the calls have happened.
>   Moreover, you are not obligated to sub invocations unless you are
>   happy with default values Mockito provides you.
>
> Such an approach separates test setup logic from test verification one
>   much better increasing readability.

and

> Few words about why mockito doesn't promote verifying stubbed methods.
>
> 1. Simplification. Back in the old days, when mock frameworks were widely unknown we've been hand-writing our stubs. But I don't remember a single case where we wanted to verify that the stub was actually called. The reason was simple: stubbed methods are implicitly verified: by the fact that stubbed value is essential in processing.
> 2. I saw tests where not having separation of stubbing and 'expecting' was actually harmful. The developer added return-value expectation because mock screamed with UnexpectedOperation. But he did not check if the value returned by mock was actually used... Simplifying stubbing puts accent on something more interesting: if stubbed value is used correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I have a a lot of calls that are *exactly* the same I just use a commonMocking-method, put the verify there and reuse it where needed. Then I keep the verfies in the actual test - this *also* makes it a lot more readable what the actual differences between each testcase is.